# Is there a function in Hive to rollup multiple records into one using a delimiter?

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql, data-analysis

I have a table with multiple lines for the same ID as below:

| ID | Company |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | CompanyA |
| 123456 | CompanyB |
| 456123 | CompanyB |
| 789123 | CompanyC |
| 789123 | CompanyD |

Is there a function in Hive that can rollup multiple records into one using a delimiter like below:

| ID | Company |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | CompanyA, CompanyB |
| 456123 | CompanyB |
| 789123 | CompanyC, CompanyD |

I tried using collect_list, but I am not getting the desired results. Hive does not have STUFF() like SQL.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to get actual values from list generated by collect set? You can use below sql to overcome that.

```
Select 
Id,
concat_ws(',', collect_set(company)) as company
From mytable
Group by id
```

Now, if you want to order data in list, then sort the data in a subquery before collect list. Use sort by instead of order by.

```
Select 
Id,
concat_ws(',', collect_set(company)) as company
From 
(Select * from mytable sort by id, company) mytable
Group by id
```